# Android: Sent message to history

Tags: android, sms

Need some help. I have this Messaging app(it doesn't really send messages, just toasts displaying that it was sent) and the problem is that I want the supposedly sent message to go directly to history with time stamp and details of what message is sent and to whom then when I clicked on it I maybe able to read it again, edit and/or resend it again. DO I really need SQLite database? and how do I implement this situation?

Comment: I have this Messaging app? my dear which app you are talking about?

Comment: I made one, but it doesn't really send messages, it just displays toast that it was sent. I wanna know how to save the sent message to history complete with details.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your looking for Status Bar Notifications.  More info and some example code is included with the documentation here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

You do not need a SQLite database to implement these notifications.  They can be triggered from Activities or Services.

Comment: My messaging app doesn't really send the message. It just displays a toast that the message is sent. I wanna know how to save the sent message to history complete with details.

Comment: @Kev Ah. If you want a fully functional messaging app that does everything but actually send the message, and you want the history to be maintained when the device is restarted, then you will need to persist the message history somewhere.  The options for doing this are delineated here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html  I don't know what your data looks like but SQLite does seem to be the best choice.

Comment: I don't really want to send the message I just need to save it somewhere then able to view/edit it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not positive if this is what you need, but check this out. I believe it will help.

http://www.xynteq.com/2011/06/adding-sent-texts-to-messaging.html

Comment: My messaging app doesn't really send the message. It just displays a toast that the message is sent. I wanna know how to save the sent message to history complete with details.